# firestore firebase does not create a collection of users even though the registration is correct

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I built a chat application with react & firebase and made the authentication in firebase by email, password, storage and firestore database, but when I try to register, firebase does not create a collection for users even though the user is registered successfully and appears in the authentication section in my account in firebase

Register.jsx code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Add from "../img/addAvatar.png";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db, storage } from "../firebase";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const Register = () => {
  const [err, setErr] = useState(false)
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const displayName = e.target[0].value;
    const email = e.target[1].value;
    const password = e.target[2].value;
    const file = e.target[3].files[0];


    try {
      const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)

const storageRef = ref(storage, displayName);

const uploadTask = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

// Register three observers:
uploadTask.on(
  (error) => {
    setErr(true)
  }, 
  () => {
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then( async(downloadURL) => {
      await updateProfile(res.user, {
        displayName,
        photoURL: downloadURL,
      });
      await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid), {
        uid: res.user.uid,
        displayName,
        email,
        photoURL: downloadURL
      });
    });
  }
);
    }catch(err){
    setErr(true)
    }
  

  }

  return (
    <div className='formContainer'>
    <div className='formWrapper'>
      <span className='logo'>Chatgram</span>
      <span className='title'>Register</span>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder='name'/>
        <input type="email" placeholder='email'/>
        <input type="password" placeholder='password'/>
        <input style={{display:'none'}} type="file" id="file"/>
        <label htmlFor="file">
          <img src={Add} alt="" />
          <span>add a photo</span>
        </label>
        <button>register</button>
        {err && <span>!! somthing wrong</span>}
      </form>
      <p>you have an account? sign in</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

export default Register

firebase.js code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "??????",
  authDomain: "??????",
  projectId: "?????",
  storageBucket: "?????",
  messagingSenderId: "??????",
  appId: "??????"
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth();
export const storage = getStorage();
export const db = getFirestore();
```

At first it was showing me this error

[image]

and Then the error no longer appears

Comment: What is your object memo4? I can't find it in your code

Comment: Also Firebase is seperated into docs and collections. I don't know how your database looks like but if you want to access a collection you need to use collection() instead of doc(). Imagine a Collection being a folder like Users and a doc is a file containing the users data. Read more @ https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en

Comment: memo4 is the name of the user that i registered

Answer (score 1):

As per @SickerDude43's comment, Firestore uses collections and documents. To access a collection, use `collection()`, and to access a specific document within a collection, use `doc()`. In your code, when adding a new user document to the "users" collection, use `collection("users")` instead of `doc("users")`. This ensures you are adding a new document to the collection. The `doc()` function is used to reference a specific document based on its ID.

```
await setDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
  uid: res.user.uid,
  displayName,
  email,
  photoURL: downloadURL
});
```